# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: java, variables, x11, init, env

I am running Raspbian with the fadecandy server, using vncserver to load an X11 instance and running a java app to drive the fadecandy controlled leds. I need this to load during the boot up process.

In /etc/init.d/ I have a bash script called fadecandy:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/fadecandy
# start fadecandy server

sudo fcserver &
sudo vncserver &
export DISPLAY=":1"
/home/pi/fadecandy/runstopturn/runstopturn &
```

runstopturn fails to execute. If I logon to the system and manually run it I get an error "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set..."

By typing the following at the prompt:

```
export DISPLAY=":1"
runstopturn
```

then everything works fine.

I need help setting the DISPLAY variable or passing it to the Java script on boot.

Comment: There isn't an X11 server running "at boot" and there isn't an X11 session that you have access to on that particular display until you log in, or manually start it up. What exactly is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: How many LEDs are we talking about exactly if it takes Linux, X11 and a JVM to blink them?

Comment: 256 - That's just for the tail lights. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP0Oil0rUnc Notice that it's more than just blinking them on and off. There's dithering as well. I've resorted to straight python with the PIM/Pillow module. No x-server required.

Comment: tripleee - I know there isn't an X11 server running at boot time. Running vncserver doesn't start up a graphical display either. As best as I can understand (which is rather limited) it simply loads and environment. It definitely satisfied the java Processing app for running headless.

Comment: Why go to all of this trouble? Now I can modify the look and style of the turn signals on the fly. Upload some new png files and I have a new look. The video shows a couple of red dots with yellow flashers. Since then I've redesigned them to be a big red "X" on each side paying homage to the Honda VTX I'm putting them on.

Comment: Matti - Is that a Finnish name?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more logs, but why are you running `vncserver` as `root`? This is probably the start of your problems.

Try running as a less-privileged user (create one if necessary), or if you really have to, run the *entire script* as `root` - but mixing and matching users will make environments and config hard to get right.

Edit: additionally, check what `/bin/sh` actually points to. On small installs, it could be a less Bash-like than you first think (i.e. you might need to use `setenv` - [some details here](https://www.ccs.uky.edu/docs/cluster/env.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nick. I'm really not that clever. I run it as root because if I don't add the sudo before both the fcserver and vncserver, they don't launch. I've even tried to sudo export DISPLAY as well. My latest effort was to include a System.setProperty("DISPLAY",":1"); in the java app. No joy. By the way, aren't all of the scripts in init.d run as root?

Answer (score 0):

Too frustrated with the issue. There's more than one way to skin a cat, or drive a fadecandy server... I'm just going to do the entire thing in python. Should be a more light weight solution and I don't need the X11 instance.

Thanks again to Nick for weighing in.

Comment: Jerrold, I've been driving a fadecandy with the node.js extensions, and found it to be very lightweight, and easy to set up.  If you end up going in that direction, let me know.  I'll be installing the project this weekend, and doing a post mortem after that.  Good luck!